# How to clear python interpreter in visual studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio

I want to create simple animation using python that will:

1. Print diagram with some data in it
2. Clear the dialog window
3. Print another diagram with some other data in it

I am supposed to use Visual Studio 2019 in this project. Sadly, os.system('cls') - I am using Windows - won't work, I get such output:

```
Some text 1
♀some text 2
```

Where in place of '♀' cleared window is expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just print a bunch of blank lines? `print("\n"*80)`

Comment: It's school project and such action is forbidden

Answer (score 0):

This is know issue and reported earlier. `os.system('cls')` prints control character and does not clear the screen.

Please see: [os.system('cls') does not clear the screen when redirect is enabled](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/246).

The error behavior is reproducible on my Windows 10 PC using Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

Note that disabling redirect output solves the issue:

[image]

Comment: @kacprk - you're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted.